# Standard deviation on Bimodal data

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, median, bimodal, interquartile

Standard deviation, whilst it is often used on normal distributions, is it a useful statistic on global temperature, both daily and yearly, given that weight of the data is towards the ends of the histograms i.e. Bimodal? This means that a very small multiple of any SD (say 1.5) will cover 100% of the data.

Example data is the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These histograms come from data such as

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: How do you wind up with more than $50\%$ in $Q1$ and $Q4$ when those are defined to contain $50\%?$

Comment: Sinusoidal data is always bimodal and has the majority of its data in Q1 and Q4.

Comment: How are you calculating that? $Q1$ is defined as the lowest quarter, and $Q4$ is defined as the highest quarter. Together, those make up $50\%$.

Comment: See above. You may be correct on normal distribution data, but not on Bimodal data. Q1 and Q4 are defined by the distribution, not the range.

Comment: That is incorrect.

Comment: Show me how on the above histograms.

Comment: It’s literally the definition of the quartiles. What, exactly, do you mean by $Q1$ and $Q4?$

Comment: "A quartile divides data into three points—a lower quartile, median, and upper quartile—to form four groups of the dataset. The lower quartile, or first quartile, is denoted as Q1 and is the middle number that falls between the smallest value of the dataset and the median. The second quartile, Q2, is also the median. The upper or third quartile, denoted as Q3, is the central point that lies between the median and the highest number of the distribution."

Comment: What about that reference disputes what I’ve written?

Comment: I define quartiles as being 25% of the data as shown above.

Comment: Good, that’s the usual definition. Now what is $25+25?$

Comment: So does SQL. http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-n-tile.html In any case what is the standard deviation of the above histograms and is it relevant?

Comment: I tried to update the question to say that q1 and q4 are towards the ends of the data instead but it has been closed so will not allow that.

Comment: Because of how they are defined, $Q1$ and $Q4$ are always towards the ends of the distribution.

Comment: So how would you word it so that it is apparent that the weight of the data is towards the ends which is contrary to normal distributions. Bimodal distributions are almost the inverse of normal distributions with the weight at the ends rather than the middle

Comment: You should have no problems editing a closed question: the entire point of closure is to give you that opportunity without people posting answers in the meantime.  Re your early comments: by definition, any quarter of the data will be observed in one quarter of the times (assuming regular, even sampling intervals).  Thus, exactly *half* the data will be in the lower or upper quartiles. That does not mean they will cover half the *range* of the values. In your first bar chart, for instance, the bottom 20% of all values are all in the lowest bar representing only 10% of the range.

Comment: I realize again that my wording leaves something to be desired.  The preponderance of the data is in the first and last quartile of the range.